# Ajax doesn't refresh html page

Tags: php, ajax

I'm new to coding. I want to refresh

> 'Test text'
>   in HTML div id='result'
>   to 
>   'Or something else'
>   in data.php file

I don't understand why it is not working, because I copied that code from video course. I'm running those pages on Microsoft WebMatrix. 
I tried to install XAMPP but couldn't start Apache server. So I ended up to WebMatrix. Thanx for helping newbie

**HTML file**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>

     function ajax_request() {
         var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
             if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                 var result = document.getElementById('result');
                 result.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

             }

         }
         xmlhttp.open('Get', 'data.php', true);
         xmlhttp.send();
     }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="ajax_request">Click me</button>
    <div id='result'>Test text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP file**

```
   <?php 
    $data = "Or something else";
    echo $data;

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button onclick="ajax_request">Click me</button>
```

must be

```
<button onclick="ajax_request();">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, man! So stupid error :// Should I delete my post/question (the error is so embarrassingly stupid) or moderators will do it?